# Display different templates based on host in Django

Tags: django, mezzanine

I'm using Mezzanine that is based on Django. I have setup a multi tenancy environment with it. So these I use:

```
example.com
sub1.example.com
sub2.example.com
```

So what Mezzanine is able to do is to display different content based on the current domain. The title of the site and the posts differ. However, I can't find a proper way to change templates based on the subdomain or the "main" domain (example.com).

**There is a setting for this in Mezzanine ([HOST_THEMES](http://mezzanine.jupo.org/docs/multi-tenancy.html)):**

```
HOST_THEMES = (('sub1', 'app_theme_1'), ('sub2', 'app_theme_2'))
```

This doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Here's a thought... (sorry I'm on my phone so I cannot post snippets) set a piece of Middleware that looks at the subdomain, and alters the location of the template files based upon what it finds.

Comment: Django Sites may be what you are looking for https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/sites/

Answer (score 0):

- Ensure you use the full hostnames in the HOST_THEMES setting (your example doesn't)
- Ensure the public facing web server (nginx, apache) is correctly forwarding the HTTP_HOST header
- Ensure you've created actual site records with the correct subdomains in the "Sites" section of Mezzanine's admin

Comment: I'm using the Django development server when testing this. How can I test this on nginx or apache? Do I have to deploy?

Comment: I was just giving you a list of things to check, so that one's not applicable to you.